# What is an efficient way to send email with possibly multiple large attachments via a WCF web service?

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, email

I am looking for the best (or at least a very good) way of doing the following:
The client passes the necessary data *(i.e. from, to, cc...subject, body etc)* as well as attachment files to the service which composes the email using the SmtpClient class and sends it to the recipient(s).
I know how to send an email with the aforementioned fields passed by the client, however I am having difficulty with the attachments, as they could potentially be more than 1 large files of any type. Is it better for the client to pass a Stream object, a byte[] (or possibly a 2D array for >1 attachments) etc. to the service?
Are there are conventions or protocols for this topic? (I'm writing a WCF web service in C#)

Any advice, code, links, etc would be appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

You could use MTOM (Message Transmission Optimization Mechanism) to pass the attachment as binary content.  Here is a good writeup: http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/archive/2009/05/14/using-mtom-with-wcf.aspx

Comment: yeah, I was thinking about using MTOM...Thx for the link

Answer (score 0):

I would send the outgoing emails to a pickup directory, which will queue them instead of sending them immediately.

Comment: That doesn't really solve my problem...Care to expound on your suggestion?